# Lightswitch query/subquery/drop down choice list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm working on a LightSwitch HTML application in VS2013 using C#. I have a main screen that allows a user to pick a site that they are authorized to use. It passes this site id to the search screen, and I want to fill the search screen with a bunch of search options to search against assets.

In the database, I have 3 tables using SQL Server:

```
Site (Id, ShortName, LongName, Description)
Unit (Id, Code, Description)
SiteUnit (Id, SiteId, UnitId)
```

for valid combinations.

Since I am passing in `SiteId` I want to present the user (among other things) a drop down of valid units they can search from (`Code` field from unit)

I have attempted to accomplish this in many ways, but so far its been unfruitful.

I have added dataitem (query) to the page on the `SiteUnit` table with a parameter of `SiteId`, and this returns the appropriate records.

Now I want to use this to filter against the `Unit` table to show the appropriate choices.

All of the appropriate foreign keys are added, but I just can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a basic understanding of LightSwitch. You cannot directly use SQL code or do multiple table joins as you would in SQL. However, if you have access to the database you can create a view and then query that view as if it were a table. The following will create a view that will list every unit for every site. Calling the view with a filter on SiteID will provide the units just for that site.

```
Create View v_UnitsBySiteID as
    SELECT Id, Code, Description 
    FROM Unit u
    INNER JOIN SiteUnit su
    ON u.ID = su.UnitID
```

Change what is returned as necessary. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another filter query against your `Unit` table using a parameter just like you did for your `SiteUnit` table. You then need to set your new parameter to the proper `UnitId`. This can be accomplished in a variety of ways.

The easiest way would be to set your Parameter Binding directly to `SiteUnitQuery.SelectedItem.UnitId`. But if you need to do other processing when the `UnitQuery` executes, you can manually set the new parameter in the `SiteUnitQuery_SelectionChanged()` method or via a button of some sort.